# axios set x-www-form-urlencoded not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

The following code didn't generate desired results:

```
import axios from 'axios'
import qs from 'qs'

var data = qs.stringify({
    'account': 'xxxxxxxx',
    'pwd': 'xxxxxxx',
});

var config = {
    method: 'post',
    url: 'http://example.com/doLogin',
    headers: { 
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    },
    withCredentials: true,
    data: data
};

axios(config).then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
})
```

I printed out axios response json and noticed that the request header object dosen't contain `"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` clause.

I also used postman with same setting, and postman works fine.

Please help.

Comment: I don't see setting headers in this example: https://github.com/axios/axios#nodejs

Comment: In this section: https://github.com/axios/axios#request-config . There's an example `headers: {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'}`

Comment: Yes, but for Node.js probably it's not required to indicate `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`